# Dropbox integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox-api

I am new to integrating drop box, but I am not quite sure how to generate a call to get the request token secret.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#request-token

I have to make a call to this url `https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token` what is the best way to do this? with c#?.

Thank you for any help you may provide

**PS:  I am just not sure which c# libraries to use for this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a .Net Dropbox library on Codeplex which looks quite good: http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sharpbox is not updated yet, they dont have all the functionalities we need like for example the "Share" function

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string response = client.DownloadString("https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token"); // Add necessary query parameters

// Parse the response
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response);
```

I included the namespaces to clarify the location of each class, but you should probably just put *using directives* at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.WebRequest is the class you want. Specifically, you'll need to call Create() with the URL and then call GetResponse() to read the result.